# Normalization across colour channels in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, normalization

I have a numpy array of (10000, 32, 32, 3) (10000 images, 32 pixels by 32 pixels, 3 colour channels) and am trying to normalize each of the last three channels individually.

To normalize across the red channel I tried using

```
testX[:,:,:,0] = (testX[:,:,:,0]-np.mean(testX[:,:,:,0]))/np.std(testX[:,:,:,0])
```

but instead of producing normalized output along the red column such as: (this is the last row of pixels in one of the images)

```
[[
      ...,
    [[-1.78, 108,  94],
     [ 0.54,  37,  21],
     [ 0.12, 136, 127],
     ..., 
     [-0.68, 172, 114],
     [ 0.97, 204, 141],
     [ 1.20, 182, 118]]]]
```

it set all of the red cells to be either 0, 1 or 255

```
[[
     ...,
    [[  0, 108,  94],
     [255,  37,  21],
     [  0, 136, 127],
     ..., 
     [  0, 172, 114],
     [  0, 204, 141],
     [  1, 182, 118]]]]
```

what am I missing about this slicing function?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Since I am trying to normalize this, would it make more sense to do something much simpler instead of bothering with normalization by colour? Such as

```
testX = testX/255
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `normalized output`? I think it would mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to take the mean of the data?

Comment: I was originally taking the mean of the data by using testX = (testX-np.mean(testX))/np.std(testX)  which worked fine, but I was seeing if doing it on a per colour basis would improve the learning of the neural net I'm training.  By normalized output I'm referring to subtracting the mean and then dividing by the std deviation which produces a normal distribution.  Though I've seen some equally useful normalization that just involves dividing each data point by the max in the array

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this might be caused by having the data type of the final numpy array set to int instead of float. See the following example, where 'x' is the image data:

```
redchannel = x[:,:,:,0]   
greenchannel = x[:,:,:,1]
bluechannel = x[:,:,:,2]
a = 0.0
b = 1.0
imgdata_min = 0
imgdata_max = 255

normalized_redchannel = a + ((( redchannel - imgdata_min)*(b - a))/(imgdata_max - imgdata_min))

# merge channels
x_with_normalized_red = np.stack((normalized_redchannel,greenchannel,bluechannel), axis=3)
print(x_with_normalized_red.astype('int32')) # prints 0/1 values
print(x_with_normalized_red.astype('float32')) # prints floating point values
```